# Create large grid in python using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, cell

I'm trying to create a large grid (1000x1000) in python using Tkinter and my first guess was to use the grid function with the following code for a 50x50 grid:

```
roomFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
roomFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
cells = {}
for row in range(50):
   for column in range(50):
       cell = Frame(roomFrame, bg='white', highlightbackground="black",
                                 highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1,
                                 width=10, height=10, padx=3, pady=3)
       cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
       cells[(row, column)] = cell
```

Everything is working fantastic except one thing: it's very very slow.

When trying to create a 100x100 it's even worse and crashes.

I want to find a way that will allow me to create a 1000x1000 grid, even with tiny cells as long as they are visible.
I also want to be able to access those cells to color them so I want to have some indexing system where I can access the cell (x,y).

I know that a solution with canvas and drawing lines on it might work but I don't think it will give the cell access functionality I want.

Comment: tkinter isn't really good at managing thousands or tens of thousands of widgets.

Comment: This isn't possible with a game engine let alone with Tkinter, without being slow. Although they are some workarounds (splitting map in to smaller parts....) but this is probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to find a way that will allow me to create a 1000x1000 grid, even with tiny cells as long as they are visible. I also want to be able to access those cells to color them so I want to have some indexing system where I can access the cell (x,y).

Tkinter wasn't designed to manage thousands or tends of thousands of widgets. There's not much you can do to improve the performance if that's what you're needing to do.

If your goal is only to change the color of each cell, I recommend using an image. You can create a blank image of a fairly large size directly address specific pixels with the `put` method.

The following only takes a second or so to come up, displaying a "grid" of 1000x1000 pixels.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(width=1000, height=1000)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
ysb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
xsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xsb.set, yscrollcommand=ysb.set)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

for x in range(0, 1000, 10):
    for y in range(0, 1000, 10):
        color = "{red}" if x >= 250 and x <= 750 and y >= 250 and y <= 750 else "{green}"
        image.put(color, (x, y, x+5, y+5))

canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]